# sql server, joining a table + retrieving data if user is friends with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Friendships](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sender] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Recipient] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsPending] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Connections] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Friendships] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_Connections_uc_IsPending]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsPending]
GO
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LiveStreams](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Sender] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Recipient] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LiveStreams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I'm getting the friends list from Friendships sucessfully by using the following (as suggested by Brian):

```
        "SELECT Id, CASE " +
        "WHEN Sender = @UserName THEN Recipient " +
        "ELSE Sender " +
        "END AS Friend, IsPending, DateTime " +
        "FROM Friendships " +
        "WHERE (Sender = @UserName " +
        "OR Recipient = @UserName) " + 
        "AND IsPending = @IsPending;";
```

However, I would like to return the rows from LiveStreams only if the sql statement matches. Meaning I want to have a method that will return all LiveStreams for all friends of @SomeUser.
Getting the friends is not the problem (see query above), but getting the LiveStreams of all friends of @SomeUser if either the friend in LiveStream is under the Sender or Recipient column.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to LiveStreams. Unfortunately as you noticed its not going to be easy since there's no FK from  Friendships and LiveStreams and you need to use either the friend in LiveStream is under the Sender or Recipient column.

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN f.sender = @UserName THEN f.recipient 
         ELSE f.sender 
       END AS friend, 
       f.ispending, 
       f.datetime 
FROM   friendships  f
       LEFT JOIN LiveStreams l
       ON f.sender = l.sender
          or f.sender = l.recipient
          or f.recipient = l.sender
          or f.recipient = l.recipient

WHERE  ( f.sender = @UserName 
          OR f.recipient = @UserName ) 
       AND f.ispending = @IsPending
```

You may want to consider making the LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM LiveStreams l
INNER JOIN Friendships f ON f.Sender = l.Sender OR f.Sender = l.Recipient OR f.Recipient = l.Sender OR f.Recipient = l.Recipient
WHERE l.Sender = @SomeUser OR l.Recipient = @SomeUser
```

This query can get a lot simpler (and *faster*) if you can narrow down your @SomeUser as either the sender or the Recipient of the stream.

I suspect a serious flaw in your table design here, as well. A stream should probably have a single *Owner*, you and you can use a separate table(s) to handle features like sending the streams to other users, favoriting streams, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies. I just want to clarify that when given @SomeUser, I need the query to lookup his/her friends from the other table and return the LiveStream values of the friends returned, in a way that either the friends have initiated or been sent the stream. I hope that I'm able to carry the idea across. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: @SomeUser has nothing to do with the stream here Joel. I am trying to get his/her friends and get their streams from LiveStreams table.